# Is "to drape a medal" correct usage?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to describe the act of an official attaching a medal to a recipient's clothing (chest) during an awards ceremony.  Is "to drape a medal" the correct usage?  I don't think "to pin a medal" sounds formal.

Comment: Well, if it's not on a ribbon or sash then you're not draping it.  "Pin on" is perfectly correct, though you could always wimp out and just say "award".

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I did think about "award" and "bestow" and felt much like you said that it was wimping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe **to pin** and **to drape** differ at all in terms of register or formality. The difference is semantic:

> **pin (v)**: attach or fasten with a pin or pins in a specified position.
>
> **drape (v)**: arrange (cloth or clothing) loosely or casually on or around something.

You may find examples of "drape a medal around someone's neck," but the action you want to describe - "attaching a medal to a recipient's clothing (chest) during an awards ceremony" - is clearly one of **pinning**, not **draping**.

As a side note, we do have the following expression in English, which is a caustic way of responding to someone's boasting:

> **Would you like a medal or a chest to pin it on?**

Comment: RT, thank you.  By the way, I don't quite understand the expression; by implying that the person who is boasting has no chest, does it try to denigrate that person as less than human? Just curious.

Comment: I don't think most people interpret the expression too deeply; rather, they simply understand the idea of "don't be such a braggart." But I've seen different explanations of the "chest" part of the expression; some say it implies the person should be more "manly", others that it relates somehow to "puffing out one's chest", which is another way of saying "boasting." I honestly don't know, but there is no strong implication that the person doesn't have a chest.

Answer (score 0):

This is just me talking from 30 years as a florist... (seen a lot of funerals) The only time I've heard "drape" a medal, is when someone puts it on a dead body lying in state, or on the casket. (Or, on a likeness of the recipient.) I don't think you use "pin" or "award" in the case of actually presenting it posthumously.